# How to use autocomplete in chrome app?

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

I'm using `autocomplete="off"` in my websites, but 2 days ago, it stopped working in Chrome app on android.

Is there any other way I can achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it in the form.

```
<form autocomplete="off">
```

Solved it in my chrome desktop browser. Chrome ignores `autocomplete="off"` in inputs

It seems that you can also get creative with jQuery to create fake invisible forms a milisecond after choosing a field so the autofill won't show up.

```
  $(".fake-autofill-fields").show();
        // some DOM manipulation/ajax here
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $(".fake-autofill-fields").hide();
        },1);
```

It seems to be the only way since it's a browser problem and not a language problem.

Comment: please read the question carefully and answer it. He is asking about the chrome android app not the desktop app